# Convert time from AM/PM to 24 hour

Tags: php, date, time

I have a time as `5:4 pm` and i want convert the time from AM/PM to 24 hour format in PHP, i try as `date('H:i',strtotime('5:4 pm'))` but this don't work and result is `16:00` in the event that it should be `17:04`. what do i do?

**DEMO:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bfd524f65ea4fa3031e55c9879aab711f31e1b37

I can not change this time.

Comment: try echo date('H:i',strtotime('05:04 pm'));

Comment: so is it in variable ? means your current time ?

Comment: 5:4 is not a valid time format.  Do you mean 5:04 or 5:40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the time string format will be same -

```
$time = explode(' ', '5:4 pm');
$temp = date_parse($time[0]);
$temp['minute'] = str_pad($temp['minute'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo date('H:i a', strtotime($temp['hour'] . ':' . $temp['minute'] . ' ' . $time[1]));
```

**Output**

```
17:04 pm
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend PHP OOP way as they are always better than any procedural way(like using `strtotime`):

```
$time = '5:04 pm';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i a', $time);
echo $date->format('H:i');//17:04
```

Please mind that you need to provide : **5:04 pm** , you **CAN NOT** use **5:4 pm** .

Reason is that no date format exist for minutes without a leading zero.

For reference see this:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

If you have to have time in that format then you will need to manipulate it after you receive your time as follows:

```
$time = '5:4 pm';//works for formats -> '5:4 pm' gives 17:04,'5:40 pm' gives 17:40
$time2 = str_replace(' ',':',$time);
$time3 = explode(':',$time2);
if(((int)$time3[1])<10)//check if minutes as over 10 or under 10 and change $time accordingly
    $time = $time3[0].':0'.$time3[1].' '.$time3[2];
else
    $time = $time3[0].':'.$time3[1].' '.$time3[2];

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:i a', $time);
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 0):

Try to capitalize AM/PM

```
date('H:i', strtotime('5:04 PM'))
```

**{EDIT}**

Replace pm with PM using `str_replace`

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime(str_replace("pm","PM",'5:04 PM')))
```

Comment: I can not change this time.

.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass 5:04 pm instead of 5:4 pm, it seems the parameter expects 2 digits for the minute format.

Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecf968c844da50e8a9eec2dc85656f49d7d20dee

Comment: I can not change this time.

Comment: It's about formatting, you don't have to change the "time" itself. You just need some function to format your date time to let strtotime() interpret it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime("05:04 PM"));
```

Comment: I can not change this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

```
$time = '5:4 pm';
$arr = explode(" ",$time);  
$arr1 = explode(":",$arr[0]);
foreach($arr1 as $k =>  $val){
    $arr1[$k] = sprintf("%02d", $val);    
}
$str = implode(":", $arr1)." ".$arr[1];
echo date('H:i',strtotime($str));
```

> pure date wont work, so I am exploding it as it is special case

I hope this will work.
Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
// 24 hours format
$date = date("H:i a",time());
// just pass time() function instead of strtotime()

echo $date;

// output
// 17:04 pm
// to run a test, do reset your system time back or forward to 5:4 pm
```

Thanks, hope this helps.

Comment: this code does not convert a given time from 12 to 24h format, it displays the current time...

Comment: yea that was my intention

Comment: so this is not an answer to the original question...